# how to NOT cut off the last char with substr?

Tags: php, substr

Got following String: http://example.de/?param=1&param2=http://example2.com/
I want to get everything behind param2=. First thought was substr, but it never gives me all behind param2=. No matter how I use it, it always returns http://example2.com (last char missing). I red the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) for this, but still no success with this.

I already tried:

```
$url = 'http://example.de/?param=1&param2=http://example2.com/';

$piece = substr($url, strpos($url, 'param2=') + 7 ,count($url)); //+7 cause of param2= should not be included
=> h

$piece = substr($url, strpos($url, 'param2=') + 7 , -count($url));
=> http://example2.com

$piece = substr($url, strpos($url, 'param2=') + 7 , +count($url));
=> h

$piece = substr($url, strpos($url, 'param2=') + 7 , -(count($url)+1));
=> http://example2.co

$piece = substr($url, strpos($url, 'param2=') + 7 , -(count($url)-1));
=>        (empty)

$piece = substr($url, strpos($url, 'param2=') + 7 , -1);
=> http://example2.com

$piece = substr($url, strpos($url, 'param2=') + 7 , -0);
=>        (empty)
```

So I never get the last char, maybe you know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: what is expect outcome?

Comment: http://example2.com/ , the '/' is always cut off. Also tried without / but then is the m missing instead.

Comment: See the Dup and lookup [`parse_url()` in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: what about using `$_GET['param2']`

Comment: either use `parse_url();`  or `explode('&param2=',$string)[1]`

Comment: parse_url() is no option for me because it automatically decodes the params.

Comment: Use explode PHP function

Comment: You do know that simply omitting the third parameter to `substr()` gives you the rest of the string? See [example](https://eval.in/657099) Docs state: _If length is omitted, the substring starting from start until the end of the string will be returned._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `explode()`:-

```
<?php

$string = 'http://example.de/?param=1&param2=http://example2.com/';

echo explode('&param2=',$string)[1];
```

Output:-https://eval.in/657097

For your query in comment, do like below:-

https://eval.in/657101

Comment: Only problem with this is if in the case that there are multiple parameters after _param2_

Comment: I'd explode a second time on  _&_ and call with index _0_

Comment: @AllenButler  check my second example link in my answer.  Glad to help you. cheers :):)

Comment: @Anant `parse_url()` should be used here